# Smallest netbook that runs Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I am looking for an ubuntu netbook that is very small. If possible, the size of the [hp 95lx](http://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_PrefLoc=1&_nkw=hp%2095lx&_fln=1&_trksid=p3286.c0.m283).  If anybody remembers those old DOS, or Windows CE devices, that were basically calculator size, with keyboards, I'm sure you can see what I mean.

I am aware of [pandora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora_%28console%29) and it seems nearly perfect (if you settle for running its custom LInux instead of ubuntu), but as it's a small privately produced unit, and not currently commercially available, I'm looking for something that IS available now in north america.

Comment: Are you specific on any Desktop Environment ? I mean Unity, Gnome, KDE etc ? because I don't think any of these would work in such a form-factor. Would be hurting to the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only device I know of that fits what you are looking for is called the Sharp NetWalker. and that will be a hard machine to find.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OMG! Ubuntu! [recently reviewed](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/the-ben-nanonote-the-worlds-smallest-linux-laptop/) a tiny Linux laptop called the Ben NanoNote. Like the Pandora, this device doesn't run Ubuntu, but as Aamir mentioned, I doubt the traditional Ubuntu flavors would do well on a device this small.

Unlike the Pandora, this device actually is [available for purchase online](https://sharism.cc/shop/product_info.php?cPath=1&products_id=1). The price is $99.

[image: The tiny Ben NanoNote compared to the Samsung Galaxy Nexus]